# Операции с датами. Как узнать, к какому периоду времени из базы относится дата?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе MySQL есть несколько записей с интервалами дат в виде

```
cid   eventDate     endDate
1     2013-04-01    2013-04-31
2     2013-05-01    2013-05-30
```

Пользователь вводит свой интервал дат в форму, н-р **2013-04-25 и 2013-05-05** после чего выводятся все даты между введенными им датами функцией

```
// Расчет интервала между сезонами
    $begin = new DateTime($startPicker);
    $end = new DateTime($endPicker);

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date){
        $startDateNew = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo $startDateNew.'<br>';
    }
    // Конец расчета интервала между сезонами
```

Получается что-то вроде

```
2013-04-25
2013-04-26
2013-04-27
2013-04-28
2013-04-29
2013-04-30
2013-05-01
2013-05-02
2013-05-03
2013-05-04
```

Разумеется, каждая из 9 дат между введенным пользователем интервалом относится к разным периодам из базы.
Необходимо между

```
foreach($daterange as $date){
        $startDateNew = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo $startDateNew.'
```

и

```
<br>';
}
```

узнать, к какой строке из базы можно отнести текущую дату startDateNew.
В голову ничего не идет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cid   eventDate     endDate
1     2013-04-01    2013-04-31
```

Для справки, в апреле 30 дней :-)

---

Узнать, к какой строке относится, можно так:

```
SELECT cid FROM intervals WHERE ? BETWEEN eventDate AND endDate;
```

Потом один раз `prepare` и много `execute`.

(`http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45e5e/1`)

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает! :)